# MVC 4: Some fields return as null when editing entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Edit view which displays some of my fields as follows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:40%; vertical-align:top">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CREATED_DATE)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CREATED_DATE)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CREATED_DATE)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.STATUS)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.STATUS, Model.Statuses)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.STATUS)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SEVERITY)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SEVERITY, Model.Severities)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SEVERITY)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PRIORITY)
            </div>
            <div id="priorityDiv" class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PRIORITY)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRIORITY)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION)
            </div>
            <div id="descriptionDiv" class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In essence I want users to be able to edit any field except for the two at the top, CREATED_DATE and LAST_MODIFIED_DATE.  However, when I hit the submit button the two date fields come back as null.  My controller code is below.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Alert alert)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        alert.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE = DateTime.Now;
        db.Entry(alert).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(alert);
}
```

Is there a way to prevent the user from editing a field in a View without the content of filed being returned to the controller as null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add them to your view in hidden fields inside the form:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CREATED_DATE)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CREATED_DATE)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)
</div>
```

This will make them post back to your `Edit` method without the user being able to edit them. You can also remove the `ValidationMessages` for this fields as they cannot be edited and therefore won't need to display validation messages.

EDIT:
As @JLRishe pointed out this would give the users the power to edit the values using their browsers debug tools.

Another solution could be to create a view specific model, and only map the values you want adjusted to your database object. More info about that here: [Real example of TryUpdateModel, ASP .NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735635/real-example-of-tryupdatemodel-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: They technically could edit them if they open the page in their browser debug tools.

Comment: Didn't think about that, they would be able to do that yes.