# TryUpdateModel with simple string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am doing a simple AJAX POST from CSHTML. In the post, I am passing a string.

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("Test","Controller"',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify({ pt: 'testString' }),
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
      }
 });
```

I want to get this value in controller as follows -

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test()
{
       var pt = string.empty;
       TryUpdateModel(pt);
       // Do some processing and return a value
       return Json(true);
}
```

But always my `pt` comes as empty. Also please do give me solution with works with value types as well.

Comment: Your controller code doesn't make sense. You are not using `planType` and declaring a new `pt` instead! The parameter of your action should be named `pt`

Comment: You don't have a model. What would be the point of `TryUpdateModel` You method needs to be `public ContentResult GetPlansData(string pt)` and pt will be the value you posted which is "teststring"

Comment: I updated my question, my questions main intent is on how to get a string (and also values types) using TryUpdateModel().

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test()
{
       var pt = Request.Params["pt"]
       // Do some processing and return a value
       return Json(true);
}
```

OR

```
class PtModel { public string pt { get; set; } }
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test()
{
        var ptModel = new PtModel();
        TryUpdateModel(ptModel);
        var language = ptModel.pt;

       // Do some processing and return a value
       return Json(true);
}
```

TryUpdateModel correct works only for objects with *properties*

Answer (score 0):

The method for the controller should be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string pt)
{
   TryUpdateModel(pt);
   // Do some processing and return a value
   return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me, why should I have a parameter `string pt`, when I am using TryUpdateModel()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735635/real-example-of-tryupdatemodel-asp-net-mvc-3